# SQL - Find number in a range of numbers

Tags: sql-server

SQL is not my forte, and I am not sure how to ask the question, some help would be much appreciated.

I need to extract a record that falls between a range of numbers.  So I have a number e.g 230, that would return a rate of 60, based on the table below.

```
MinR    MaxR   Rate
1       3000    60.00
3001    5000    50.00
5001    7000    48.00
7001    10000   45.00
10000   999999  43.00
```

Logically I have tried *MinR >=237 and MaxR <=237*, to no avail.

Is there a simple statement to achieve this, or should I be tackling this more programatically (cursor, If..then, etc)

Many thanks
Graham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BETWEEN` as follows:

```
SELECT Rate
FROM YourTable
WHERE 230 BETWEEN MinR AND MaxR - 1
```

Used -1 part so that you do not get two records for one input.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, you just have your logic backwards. Let's look at `MinR >=237 and MaxR <=237` and plug in the numbers from the first row:

```
1 >= 237 AND 3000 <= 237
```

Is that condition satisfied? Obviously not: 1 is not greater or equal than 237. It works if you do it the other way around:

```
MinR <= 237 AND MaxR >= 237
```

or, to improve readability (and to avoid this kind of mistake in the future):

```
237 BETWEEN MinR And MaxR
```